# Group by a subquery in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Say I have a query such as the following:

```
   SELECT 
        EmployeeName, 
        DepNo,
        sum(wages)
   FROM
       Employees
   GROUP BY
       EmployeeName, 
       DepNo
```

Then I have some data in another table called Departments such as:

```
DepNo DepName
1     Accountants
2     HR
3     IT
```

How could I swap the Employee.DepNo to be the Department.DepName?

I tried adding a nested select but I ran into an issue when grouping:

```
   SELECT 
        EmployeeName, 
        (SELECT DISTINCT DepName FROM Departments WHERE Employees.DepNo = Departments.DepNo) AS DepName,
        sum(wages)
   FROM
       Employees
   GROUP BY
       EmployeeName, 
       DepName
```

Comment: Have you had a look at a `JOIN`?

Comment: Yeah a join would solve it. I just wondered if there was another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a subquery, just `JOIN` to the other table and then return the column in the `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT E.EmployeeName,
       D.DepName,
       SUM(Wages) AS Wages
FROM Employees E
     JOIN Departments D ON E.DepNo = D.DepNo
GROUP BY E.EmployeeName,
         D.DepName
```

Answer (score -2):

Since you are asking for another answer, You may update your query to -

```
SELECT 
        EmployeeName, 
        (SELECT DISTINCT DepName
           FROM Departments
          WHERE Employees.DepNo = Departments.DepNo) AS DepName,
        sum(wages)
   FROM
       Employees
   GROUP BY
       EmployeeName, 
       Employees.DepNo
```

Comment: Oh right, so you're grouping by Departments.DepNo rather than Employee.DepNo. Interesting... How is it that we can reference Department.DepNo without a join then in our group by?

Comment: This won't work, @Fusiozii . `Departments` has no context in the outer query: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=867dc900b574c2a1b93e5418f36c31d0).

Comment: I did think that, thanks for confirming - didnt look right

Comment: You could, however, put `Employees.DepNo` in the `GROUP BY` and it would work, however, an explicit JOIN is still the way to go, @Fusiozii .

Comment: @Fusiozii, I have corrected my answer now. Thanks to Larnu for pointing out error.